# How do I fix this dereference of nullable error?

Tags: java, null, dereference

I've been trying to get rid of the dereference of a possible null-reference graph for the longest time, but nothing seems to work.

This is my original code:

```
if (!pluto.get(boxer.getName()).contains(boxer)) {
   pluto.get(boxer.getName()).add(boxer);
}
```

where pluto is private final Map> pluto;

and I have also tried

```
if (pluto.get(boxer.getName()) != null) {
        if (!pluto.get(boxer.getName()).contains(boxer)) {
                pluto.get(boxer.getName()).add(boxer);
        }
}
```

But this also doesn't work. Please help.

[dereference.of.nullable] dereference of possibly-null reference pluto.get(boxer.getName())

Comment: What pluto.get(boxer.getName()) returns?

Comment: can you please share full code?

Comment: it returns the set of strings that it is mapped to. I don't know why, but stack overflow removed my implementation for my graph. it is private final Map<String, Set<String>> pluto

Comment: There might be two possibility one map is null and another possibility is boxer.getName is null also you can verify by run your code is debug mode so you can inspect the element and check what is getting null.

Comment: You would need to check if pluto is null or if boxer is null before calling "if (pluto.get(boxer.getName()) != null)". If any of them is null it will throw a NullpointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to check for nulls.

```
if (pluto != null && pluto.get(boxer.getName()) != null && !pluto.get(boxer.getName()).contains(boxer)) {
    pluto.get(boxer.getName()).add(boxer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if your map is null?

try this:

```
if (isNull(pluto)) { // import static java.util.Objects.isNull;
   return;        // to minimise nesting
}

Optional.ofNullable(pluto.get(boxer.getName()))
        .filter(value -> !value.isEmpty())
        .ifPresent(value -> { /*do whatever you want*/ });
```